# Java: EpochSecond in Hexadecimal format

Tags: java, binary, numbers, hex, byte

I am working with a Web Service that is expecting the EpochSecond in  an 8 hexadecimal bytes string.

I am using this:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();    
Long.toHexString(now.getEpochSecond());
```

that gives me something like this **593ad84b** , that the Web Service returns me an invalid data, but I would say that the format is corrent, right ?

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation of what the service expects?

Comment: I saw a sample with ""deadbeefcafebabe", but on the other hand on the doc. it says that " It must be an 8 hexadecimal bytes string."

Comment: Your code looks ok, maybe the server expects it to be all caps, or to start with `0x` or something. If it's something internal to your project, is there someone you can ask? I assume the idea is to accept timestamps like [these](https://www.epochconverter.com/hex), and you seem to match that.

Comment: no, its external

Comment: Maybe you need to add leading zeros to complete the 8 bytes on this ***593ad84b*** and or adding the 0x

Comment: If it's external maybe link us to the document you are looking at, maybe we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of the word “bytes” is confusing.  It could mean:

- “a String whose hex digits repreent eight bytes,” which would require *sixteen* hex digits (because two hex digits are needed to represent one byte value)
- “a String containing eight ASCII characters” (the String itself takes up eight bytes in most encodings)

Based on the sample you’ve cited, I suspect it’s the first case, which means your String must contain sixteen hex digits:

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
String seconds = String.format("%016x", now.getEpochSecond());
```

Comment: Great answer, you're probably right. This gives something like`00000000593ae34c`.

Comment: indeed, this was the issue :-)